# Specific Laravel route suddenly not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a very mysterious problem. One of my routes is suddenly not working, all other routes works fine.

I get no errors, just an empty white blank page.

Even if i just return a string, it gives me nothing

```
public function create()
{
    return "Create";
}
```

The route:

```
Route::get('/start/user/create', array(
    'as' => 'user/create',
    'uses' => 'UserController@create'
));
```

The link:

```
<a class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="{{ URL::route('user/create') }}"> {{Lang::get('strings.create_customer')}}</a>
```

Im using MAMP and restarted the server and nothing helps.

EDIT: I tryed to make a completely new route, function in controller and view that simply just output a string. Its the same, it only gives me blank page.

EDIT 2: My application realy have som problem with the route `start/user/create`. If i change it to `start/user/bullshit/create` for example, everything works. So what can this be? Are there som kind of cache somewhere that always gives me blank pages with the route `start/user/create`. Its the **only** route that i have problems with.

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? It be some php error anywhere else that causes your blank page

Comment: It gives no errors in php_error.log

Comment: Show us your `routes.php` file.

Comment: Wasn't it supposed to be `'as' => 'user.create'`?

Comment: It is up to you how to name your routes. I prefer name them as the actual route.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the solution, but try this as route to rule out any problems with the controller class:

```
Route::get('/start/user/create', function()
{
    return 'This works!';
});
```

And then go directly to the url /start/user/create
Hope it helps you in some way.

Comment: It does not work. However if i change it to `start/whateverhere/create` it will show "This works!"

Comment: Show us your routes.php file. My guess is that you have another route that is matching before this route is defined.

Try to add this route to the top of the routes.php file, or remove all other routes.

You can see all routes in a good format if you run php artisan routes as well.

Comment: As @mattiashallstrom mentioned it could be that you in your routes.php a route like `/start/user/{id}` which gets called before the `/start/user/create`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not solved but by using resourceful routes instead its working. Code is cleaner too so i guess this is a better approach anyway.

```
Route::resource('start/user', 'UserController',
        array('names' => array('create' => 'user/create',
                                'index' => 'user/index',
                                'show'  => 'user/show',
                                'edit'  => 'user/edit',
                                'update'=> 'user/update',
                                'store' =>  'user/store',
                                'destroy'   =>'user/destroy')
));
```